# Positioning a fixed element just off the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a home page where one div, lets call it home, takes up the whole browser window. So that when you load it it covers the whole page. I have found many guides on how to do that. What I am having trouble is that I want content under home to be just off screen so you have to scroll to it. I think it would be be best to do this with fixed positioning and setting top to the browser height. Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>
        .overlay{
            opacity:0.8;
            background-color:#ccc;
            position:fixed;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            top:0px;
            left:0px;
            z-index:-1;
        }

        .stuff {
            position: relative;
            top: 400px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="overlay">
        <h1>Stuff</h1>
    </div>


    <p class="stuff" ">help</p>

</body>
```

So my question is what way can I set the height of the element stuff so that it is the browser windows height. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the new CSS units `vw`, `vh` etc: [Viewport Sized Typography](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

An element with `width: 100vw; height: 100vh;` will take up all the viewport size, which is exactly the size of the browser window.

For completeness: [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: Thank you this worked great. here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/seegxtdt/3/ How long has this been around?

Comment: hmm I just realized after testing that it doesn't seem to work on iphones. Which you did mention. looks like it won't work on iOS 8 ether so I will ether not be able to use this or have to make iOS specific version. Web development is so fragmented :(

Answer (score 0):

You might try using absolute positioning:

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.stuff {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: lightgreen;
    top: 100%;
}
```

Also see [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/amsc7L5a/).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you does work great but I like the effect of the fixed content getting slowly covered up. Is there a way to do it when it is fixed?

Comment: It also works when you fix position `.overlay`, [check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/amsc7L5a/1/). It won't work if you make `.stuff` fixed.